# Phonegap build for iPhone - Clarifications

Tags: iphone, phonegap-build

As I understand and correct me if I'm wrong:

In order to create an iPhone app using phoegap build I can choose one of two options:

1. Application distribution through the Apple Store - code - QR does not work and must upload the file .ipa to the store.
2. Distributing application using Ad Hoc mode - I have to specify in advance the devices that can download the app.

There is a way to generate a valid application that open to everyone, but not in the store?

How can I create something similar to ad hoc mode but open to everyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't open your app to everyone without uploading to app-store.

**Ad hoc** limited to 100 devices.

**Enterprise**  is for internal distribution in companies with more than 500 employees.

**App store** is the option to share anyone with an iPhone can have access to the application.

**For testing purpose**,You don't want to upload the app in to Appstore.

> Sign up for the iPhone Developer Program
>
> Generating a Certificate Signing Request
>
> Logging in to the iPhone Developer Program Portal
>
> Create Developer Certificate , APP ID, Add devices(it must include all
>   the device unique id in which devices you are going to run),
>   provisioning profiles.
>
> Download and Use Developer Certificate and provisioning profiles for
>   creating and testing your app in registered devices

For Distribution, do the same for distribution mode.

Please read more [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS) to getting started with iOS